# blogdown with rbind domain not updating after pushing to github

Tags: r, github, blogdown

Hopefully this is a quick fix, I have not had issues in the past with this but...

I added some new posts to my rbind website davidjohnbaker.rbind.io via the new_post() function (hire-me-as-a-datascientist- iii AND iv.Rmd) and when I uses serve_site(), the website builds just fine in my RStudio viewer.

The problem comes when I push to github, the changes are not reflected on my website.

I took a look at repository here ( https://github.com/davidjohnbaker1/davidjohnbaker ) and posts that render just fine appear to be similar to my two new posts.

Is there some step that I have absent-mindedly skipped in this process?

Comment: Did you deploy via Netlify or something else?

Comment: It was at first via Netlify, but it's now hosted via rbind ( https://github.com/rbind )

Comment: Check the build log on Netlify and see if there are any errors: https://app.netlify.com

Comment: I checked Netlify and there were build errors. I was using git-lfs to track my csv files and there was some sort of conflict with some csv files I had absent mindedly put in my drafts folder. After removing them the website deployed just fine. Thank you!